# sfdx auth:jwt:grant: Unexpected arguments: -f

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin, jenkins, cicd, jenkinsfile

I am trying to connect Jenkins to the SF sandbox. I am stuck on the auth step, where I receive this kind of error:

```
ERROR running auth:jwt:grant:  Unexpected argument: Pipeline@tmp/secretFiles/e56a52e6-fad5-41c3-b303-1e53a98632a0/server.key
See more help with --help
```

My Jenkinsfile command:

```
            withEnv(["HOME=${env.WORKSPACE}"]) {
                    withCredentials([file(credentialsId: '3526cc73-4827-4bae-9d6a-a9dd40ecc765', variable: 'server_key_file')]) {
                        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        // Authenticate to Salesforce using the server key.
                        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

                        stage('Authorize to Salesforce') {
                            rc = command "/usr/local/bin/sfdx auth:jwt:grant --instanceurl ${SF_INSTANCE_URL} --clientid ${SF_CONSUMER_KEY} --username ${SF_USERNAME} --setalias partial -f $server_key_file"
```

I tried different workarounds, including replacing $server_key_file with the actual path to the servey.key on my machine. No use.

Meanwhile, I can successfully connect to the org from the terminal:

```
****** JWT % sfdx auth:jwt:grant --clientid ********************************** \
--jwtkeyfile server.key --username ***************
Successfully authorized *************** with org ID *************
```

I quadruple-checked if the consumer key is correct. I re-created the connected app in SF. I tried to add the file to the pipeline parameters. Still no use.

Please help, I ran out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The "f" flag for this command only uses a single dash

so it's `-f <keyfile>`
and not `--f <keyfile>` as you currently have

Double-dashes are generally used for flags that are words, whereas single-dashes are generally used for flags that are single letters

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It was a --jwtkeyfile there before, I fixed the string. Still, the same error.

Comment: @OleksandrHoncharuk Also, any spaces in an argument means you'll need to enclose the argument in quotes. Not familiar enough with Jenkins to know how `rc = command " ..."` behaves.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and replace the necessary fields

```
def SF_CONSUMER_KEY=env.SF_CONSUMER_KEY
def SF_USERNAME=env.SF_USERNAME
def SERVER_KEY_CREDENTALS_ID=env.SERVER_KEY_CREDENTALS_ID
def SF_INSTANCE_URL = env.SF_INSTANCE_URL ?: "https://login.salesforce.com"

def toolbelt = tool 'toolbelt'
```

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Run all the enclosed stages with access to the Salesforce
// JWT key credentials.
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
withEnv(["HOME=${env.WORKSPACE}"]) {
    
    withCredentials([file(credentialsId: SERVER_KEY_CREDENTALS_ID, variable: 'server_key_file')]) {

        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Authorize the Dev Hub org with JWT key and give it an alias.
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

        stage('Authorize DevHub') {
            rc = command "${toolbelt}/sfdx auth:jwt:grant --instanceurl ${SF_INSTANCE_URL} --clientid ${SF_CONSUMER_KEY} --username ${SF_USERNAME} --jwtkeyfile ${server_key_file} --setdefaultdevhubusername --setalias HubOrg"
            if (rc != 0) {
                error 'Salesforce dev hub org authorization failed.'
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Could you, please, show your setup for the toolbelt, if possible?